# is it possible to spit out help as default argument when nothing is passed?

Tags: python, argparse

In python's argparse, is it possible to spit out help as default argument when nothing is passed  or if some Argparse Exception occurs?

Comment: You should be able to use a `try/except` block to handle any exceptions.

Comment: Dealing with the "nothing passed" should be pretty easy: just check that resulting `args`. Regarding exceptions raised by `argparse` I doubt that you should catch them. They indicate an internal error that you probably don't know how to deal with and just printing the help message might mean you are hiding a bug in your code or in the `argparse` code.

Comment: if you try git send-email if incorrect values are passed to argument all help is displayed.

Comment: If you want to know how to print the help - pretty straightforward `parser.print_help()`

Comment: You mean you want more than the short “usage” help?

Comment: @C.B. : using print help is exactly what I was looking for, but the help message doesn't recognize `\n` and whole sentence is coming in one line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If having zero arguments should trigger the help message, that implies that at least one of your options isn't really optional. Make sure you have at least one positional argument  (i.e., one whose name is not prefixed with "--") defined:

```
p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
p.add_argument("foo", help="Required argument")
```

Then, if your script isn't called with the argument for `foo`, the usage message should be triggered.

Answer (score 0):

The `parser` uses `sys.argv[0]` for the default `prog` value, and `sys.argv[1:]` as input to `parse_args`.  You too can access, and even modify, that array.

```
import argparse
import sys

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser....
parser.add_argument...

if not sys.argv[1:]:
    # parser.print_help(); parser.exit()
    # or
    # parser.parse_args(['-h'])
    # or
    sys.argv.append('-h')

args = parser.parse_args()

# your code to use args
```